# jboss 7.1 project deployment classnotfound

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jboss, intellij-idea

We are currently trying to deploy a spring-mvc/hibernate based project as a war file to a new ubuntu server we set up. We developed the solution using intellij on windows machines, and are deploying it to a ubuntu vm. The project compiles and works perfectly on our dev machines. We're deploying the war to the standard deployments folder in jboss 7.1. When we try to hit the site we are getting the following error...

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Scrolling further down the root root cause is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.api.Controllers.DecisionEngineController from [Module "deployment.Juno_war.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:415)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1284)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1255)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1332)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:337)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:316)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:303)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1174)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:101)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:150)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

We're new to the java stack, and we think this is a classpath issue, but we're not sure how to troubleshoot it in jboss. One thing to note is the generated manifest.mf file in the war only has the line "Manifest-Version: 1.0" in it. I'm not sure if more needs to go in there. The DecisionEngineController is the main call to a sprigmvc based api and I'm not sure how to get the project to see it.

Thanks for any help resolving the error.

Comment: Where is `com.company.api.Controllers.DecisionEngineController` located? Is it in a separate JAR? If so, where?

Comment: It's located in another module inside of the war file we're deploying. The war loads successfully on our windows jboss setup.

Comment: If it's in `/WEB-INF/lib`, than it should be visible. Check if your JDK version matches and if the package name is valid (there's a capital 'C' in there, which is quite unusual)

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you the JDK versions were mismatched. We fixed the ubuntu version and things are good now!

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem, when we were building and deploying project from Eclipse. We solved it with help from comment by Szymon Biliński.

Problem was caused by mismatched JDK. We were using Java 7 in Eclipse and Maven, but JBoss was taking JDK from JAVA_HOME environment variable where was Java 1.6.

So change JAVA_HOME to Java 7 home folder and problem solved.:)